# PHP check if session from session folder is active

Tags: php, session, session-state, expired-sessions

I need to check if each session over my website is still active or not.
I used to cycle over each session in the folder given by the php command `session_save_path()`, the problem is that even if a session expires, the respective folder doesn't modify at all.

How can I solve this? I have **PHP 5.3**, otherwise I would have tried something like `session_status()`, which I think can solve my problem.

Here's my code:

```
$sessionNames = scandir(session_save_path());

foreach($sessionNames as $sessionName) {
    $sessionName = str_replace("sess_","",$sessionName);
    if(strpos($sessionName,".") === false) { //This skips temp files that aren't sessions
        session_id($sessionName);
        session_start();

        // CHECK IF THE SESSION IS ACTIVE OR EXPIRED

        session_write_close();

    }
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: PHP 5.3 has been EOL for ages now. Please consider upgrading as it would both solve your problem and keep your application way more secure.

Comment: Why are you trying to do this?

Comment: Thanks @Loek! Actually I'm upgrading it in some months, I was just searching for some quick solution for now

Comment: @marekful to get the users' logs using an external script executed in the crontab

Comment: If you can start the session, it is obviously not expired - or how would you define that state otherwise if not by session files present or absent?

Comment: @NicoHaase if I close my webpage without logging out, wait 30 minutes, then reopen it, it redirects me to the login page, but the session file is still there exactly as it was.

Comment: The session files don't go away when the session is closed or ended. The probability of a session file being removed is based on variables in the PHP ini file. IMO you should not be looking at or using the session files directly.

Comment: If you still want to go that way, write some timestamp to each session (this causes the file to be updated on each request while the session is active). Then you can find all files that are older than your session lifetime, those will be the expired ones

Comment: @NicoHaase can you explain how? I have to save in session something like current timestamp and it should update by itself while the session is active? I don't completely understand. Thank you!

Comment: ...it should be updated on each request, so if you have a common header or footer, just call `$_SESSION['lastRequest'] = time()`